# Ошибка при обрезке изображений в gulp-responsive

Tags: node.js, gulp

Использую пакет gulp-responsive для gulp. С помощью него уменьшаю изображения и хочу уменьшить его до определенной ширины вот так:

```
gulp.task('previews', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/img/works/*.{png,jpg}')
    .pipe(responsive({
      '*': [
        {
          width: 375,
          height: 400,
          rename: {
            suffix: '_preview',
            extname: '.jpg',
          },
          crop:{
            gravity: "north"
          }
        },
        {
          rename: {
            suffix: '_full',
            extname: '.jpg',
          }
        }
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(imagemin({progressive: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/img/works'));
});
```

И опция `crop:{ gravity: "north" }` не работает, выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Подождите, переделаю вопрос

Comment: Оформите сообщение об ошибке текстом, по картинке никто это не найдет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно использовал crop. Нужно передавать не объект, а строку

Например: `crop: "north"`

Можно использовать `north, northeast, east, southeast, south, southwest, west, northwest, center, centre`

Нашел это тут http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-resize/#crop

```
gulp.task('previews', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/img/works/*.{png,jpg}')
    .pipe(responsive({
      '*': [
        {
          width: 375,
          height: 400,
          withMetadata: false,
          rename: {
            suffix: '_preview',
            extname: '.jpg',
          },
          crop: "north"
        },
        {
          rename: {
            withMetadata: false,
            suffix: '_full',
            extname: '.jpg',
          }
        }
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(imagemin({progressive: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/img/works'));
});
```